# Best way to avoid hardcoded strings in nested KVO keypaths

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

When registering to observe an object via KVO I write this code to avoid hardcoded strings:

```
[myObject addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(myProperty))
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];
```

Note the NSStringFromSelector. It protects me at compile-time in the event that I change the name of myProperty and forget I had something observing it.

But the situation is more complicated when using nested properties, e.g., "myProperty1.myProperty2"

My naive solution is to use macros like the following:

```
#define KEYPATHSTRING1(a) NSStringFromSelector(@selector(a))
#define KEYPATHSTRING2(a, b) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(a)), NSStringFromSelector(@selector(b))]
#define KEYPATHSTRING3(a, b, c) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(a)), NSStringFromSelector(@selector(b)), NSStringFromSelector(@selector(c))]
```

Any better or standardized solutions out there? Searches on Google and SO turned up nothing for me that addressed this particular question.

Comment: I understand your point but felt my question's scope was defined well enough to warrant posting this question. I could define "better" to be objective -- correct, complete, automatically extensible (i.e., don't write 1 line for each number of variables) -- but I figured those sorts of objective considerations would be readily apparent to any reader. Moreover, I couldn't find any resources on what I consider to be a valid topic of inquiry. Apologies for offending any rules or conventions.

Comment: It seems to me that this situation could arise quite commonly and my thinking is that someone out there has solved it elegantly. Apparently that is not the case. So, yes, another mind agreeing that there is not a more elegant solution would be helpful. Or an answer from someone who is a wizard at preprocessor macros that condenses my clunky solution into a one-liner that handles an arbitrary number of variables would also be welcome. I don't appreciate the personal dig. I'm not here for a pat on the back, bud.

Comment: And if you want me to delete this question just tell me. I don't pretend to be an SO expert. But I do genuinely feel like this is a valid, unanswered question that belongs in the knowledge base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this (or even compiling it), but you could look at using a variadic helper method:

```
+ (NSString *)keyPathFromSelectors:(SEL)firstArg, ...
{
    NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);

    for (SEL arg = firstArg; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, SEL))
    {
        [keys addObject:NSStringFromSelector(arg)];
    }

    va_end(args);

    return [keys componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, very interesting, thanks so much I will try this out and let you know my thoughts. I think this is better than my solution for two reasons. (1) It avoids preprocessor macros, which I generally like to do because macros can obscure the code actually being compiled; and (2) it handles an arbitrary number of arguments. Kudos if it actually works.

Comment: So I really like this approach but I am running into an issue and I'm not knowledgeable with variable args. I ran the method three times, first with one variable (selector), then with three, than with the same single variable I used the first time. The first two worked, the second crashed and the value of the arg in the for loop at time of crash was some kinda of garbage/bad memory address/etc. The exception thrown was unable to insert nil into the keys array.

Comment: Did you terminate the arguments with nil?

Comment: Let me go ahead and facepalm while reiterating "I'm not knowledgeable with variable args." LOL. I will try this out, but I'm quite certain it will work. :) Thanks so much, I'll be accepting this is my preferred answer after confirmation.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention. In your answer the return type should be "NSString *" not "NSString" -- I can't submit an edit because SO says edits have to be at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I use EXTKeyPathCoding.h from libextobjc. You can check how they do same at https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTKeyPathCoding.h

Comment: I do appreciate this answer and this is exactly along the lines I was looking for, but I'm waiting on Wain's response to my comment because I'd prefer to avoid macros altogether where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 adds `#keyPath()` to generate a key path string from a "property chain".

```
let keyPathString = #keyPath(MyType.myProperty1.myProperty2)
```

The tokens inside the function are *not* Strings and will be checked by the compiler.